# If there is more than 1 person harassing you online, are separate court orders required to identify each one?

Tags: email, online, harassment, court-order

If there is more than 1 email account harassing you online, do you need to obtain separate court orders to identify each one, or is one order sufficient?

What if one of the accounts you’re naming is determined to not be harassing?

Comment: I would add that there is not, in general, a legal remedy for being harassed online. Generally, one must show an imminent threat to your health and safety or something similar to get judicial relief for online harassment.

Answer (score 4):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

> If there is more than 1 email account annoying you online, do you need to obtain separate court orders to identify each one, or is one order sufficient?

A judge could order an email provider to unmask multiple accounts with one court order.  Judges are not really restricted in the number of things they can do per order, as long as it's within their jurisdiction.

> What if one of the accounts you’re naming is determined to not be harassing?

Then the judge would be unlikely to order that one unmasked.  It wouldn't prevent the others from being unmasked, if the requirements for such an order to be issued were otherwise met.